# Include PHP File: 2 Different Domains On The Same Server

Tags: php, path, include, include-path

I have been looking for this everywhere, but cannot find a solution.

I have PHP files on www.domainA.com. I am trying to include files from that domain to www.domainB.com. Both of these accounts are on the same server.

I am using absolute pathing to do this:

```
/path/to/my/site/public_html/include.php
```

But I am keep getting the permission deny error:

```
Warning: include(/home/domainA_account/public_html/folder/include.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/domainB_account/public_html/file.php
```

I understand why this permission error is displaying, but I do not know how to fix this?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If they are domains under different account numbers with the hosting provider then you are SOL.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to duplicate the file in your two domains while ensuring they are kept in sync, using a version control system or a deployment script.

Consider your include.php as a third party library that need to be updated in your two environments, and ensure that a process (an automated one if you can...) ensure force domains to be in sync.